# Creating multiple accounts using a shell script and standard input

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to figure out how to make a shell script that will generate new users, a randomly generated password using `openssl rand -base64 12`, UID, GID, Any description, and the Home directory for the users in chronological order then pipe to new users in a different command with correct syntax.

To make it simple I need to run the script using the standard input from the command newusers for the first user then generate the other 4 users by adding 1 seen below. The output will be something similar to:

```
user01:generatedpassword:1001:1001:Description:/home/user01:/bin/bash
user02:generatedpassword:1002:1002:Description:/home/user02:/bin/bash
user03:generatedpassword:1003:1003:Description:/home/user03:/bin/bash
user04:generatedpassword:1004:1004:Description:/home/user04:/bin/bash
user05:generatedpassword:1005:1005:Description:/home/user05:/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by what you mean but you should add a variation of the following lines to your script:

```
useradd usr01
```

and then

```
password=`openssl rand -base64 12`
echo $password | passwd --stdin usr01
```

This will mean you can see the password and it just doesn't assign it to the usr01 without you knowing what it is.

Comment: I do not need to know what the password is, the script does not need to show the actual password just the hash.